# NPM/Yarn Watch won't watch .twig files (tailwind, webpack, laravel-mix)

Tags: npm, webpack, tailwind-css

I have an issue since upgrading packages on a new theme I'm building in Timber & Twig for WordPress. I have older versions of build tools that work no issue.

**The problem**

When I run `yarn watch`, source SCSS/JS files are watched by the compiler with no issue, however the .twig files within my folders are not watched for changes.

**The Configuration**

***Webpack.mix.js***

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

// Define autoprefixer as a PostCSS plugin
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

mix.js('assets/src/js/app.js', 'assets/dist/')
   .sass('assets/src/scss/app.scss', 'assets/dist/')
   .options({
       processCssUrls: false,
       postCss: [
           tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
           autoprefixer(), // add autoprefixer
       ],
   })


// Enable versioning (cache-busting) in production
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
    mix.purgeCss(); // Optionally, enable PurgeCSS in production for smaller CSS files
}
```

***Tailwind.config.js***

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: [
    './views/**/*.twig',
    './assets/dist/**/*.js',
    './**/*.php'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

***Package.json***

```
{
  "name": "castle",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The \"_s\" for Timber: a dead-simple theme that you can build from. The primary purpose of this theme is to provide a file structure rather than a framework for markup or styles. Configure your Sass, scripts, and task runners however you would like!",
  "main": "webpack.mix.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.10",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "css-loader": "~3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.5",
    "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "postcss-loader": "~3.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
}
```

You can see from the examples above, the Tailwind config contains the Twig file extension in the content to watch. All other files like JS/CSS/SCSS files get watched as desired and compile no issue.

Also, when running `yarn prod` it doesn't compile down properly and gives the following error:

```
ERROR in ./assets/src/scss/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: PostCSS plugin postcss-purgecss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
```

However, you can see that PostCSS is up to date in the package.json file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.